# Obtener el máximo valor de una tuple que contiene tuples y listas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola tengo esta tuple `(5, (1,2), [[1],[2]])` como puedo sacar el máximo valor si hay dentro una lista y una tuple.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Luis, el título de la pregunta no termina de concordar con lo que luego expones. ¿Deseas buscar el máximo valor (suponiendo que todos son valores numéricos) de la lista en todos sus niveles (5 en este caso) o ordenarla?

Comment: @FJSevilla una disculpa me distraje al momento de poner el título.

Comment: No pasa nada, solo es que era confuso. Entonces lo que quieres es que dado por ejemplo `(5, (1,2), [[10],[2]])` obtener el máxino, que en este caso es 10 ¿Verdad? Se presupone que no sabes a pripory el numero de anidamientos.

Comment: @FJSevilla exacto en tu ejemplo sería el 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que tienes una tupla que contiene a su vez listas y tuplas anidadas y que a priori no se sabe la estructura, lo único que se me ocurrre es aplanar la tupla de forma que si tienes:

```
(5, (1,2), [[1],[2]])
```

Obtengas:

```
(5, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

De forma que podemos aplicar la función preconstruida `max` sobre ella.

No recuerdo que exista una forma preconstruida en la stdlib para algo así, por lo que habría que crear una función que lo haga. Esto se puede hacer de forma iterativa o recursiva. Usando recursividad se puede implementar de distintas formas, algunas de ellas son:

- Usando la metaclase `collections.Iterable`:

  ```
  import collections

  def aplanar(iterable):
      for item in iterable:
          if isinstance(item, collections.Iterable):
              yield from aplanar(item)
          else:
              yield item
  ```
- Comprobando la existencia del método `__iter__`:

  ```
  def aplanar(iterable):
      for item in iterable:
          if hasattr(item, '__iter__'):
              yield from aplanar(item)
          else:
              yield item
  ```
- Usando `try-except`:

  ```
  def aplanar(iterable):
      for item in iterable:
          try:
              yield from aplanar(item)
          except:
              yield item
  ```

Según las etiquetas, usas Python 3, lo digo porque este código no funciona en Python 2 al usar `yield from`. En todo momento usamos un generador por lo que es eficiente en cuanto al uso de memoria, si la lista tiene una cantidad exagerada de anidamientos es posible superar el límite de recursividad, aunque no creo que esto se de en una aplicación real. Si se diera el caso, siempre podemos hacerla iterativa.

Su uso es simple, solo usamos `max` sobre la salida de la función directamente:

> >>> t = (5, (1, 2), [[10], [2]])
>   >>> print(max(aplanar(t)))
>   10
>   >>> t = (5, (1, 2, [2, 8]), [[1, [14, 4]], [2]])
>   >>> print(max(aplanar(t)))
>   14

Obviamente se puede usar de la misma manera `min`, `sum`, etc.

Las funciones aplanan independientemente del tipo, si por ejemplo tenemos `[1, ['abc']]` obtendremos `(1, 'a', 'b', 'c')`. Modificando el condicional se puede hacer que no rompa las cadenas o cualquier otro objeto iterable para obtener `(1, 'abc')`. Para el caso que nos ocupa no importa demasiado esto ya que `max` lanza una excepción en el instante que se topa con datos heterogéneos que no tengan un orden natural (como `str` e `int`).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me había surgido esa duda.

Answer (score 2):

Otra forma es simplemente convertir la tupla en un string y luego usando re.findall puedes extraer los que son números y de allí sacar el máximo:

```
import re
t=str((5, (1,2), [[1],[2]]))
M=[]   #para almacenar los números
for l in re.findall('\d+', t):   #lista con los números en el string
    M.append(int(l))
max(M)
```

O Más eficiente si usamos la sugerencia de @FJsevilla:

```
import re
t=str((5, (1,2), [[1],[2]]))
maximo = max(int(l) for l in re.findall('\d+', str(t)))
maximo
```

Comment: Hola Cristiam este método es bastante simple y funciona bién para este caso concreto, puedes mejorarlo y hacerlo más eficiente usando un generador por compresión: `maximo = max(int(l) for l in re.findall('\d+', str(t)))`, donde `t` es la lista original. Si quieres puedes agregarlo a la respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Tienes razón. Añadido y muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, no interesan todos los resultados intermedios, sólo el valor máximo. En lugar de *aplanar* primero la lista para buscar luego el máximo, resultará más eficiente ir calculando el máximo a medida que vamos procesando la lista:

```
def flatmax(it):
    if hasattr(it, "__iter__"):
        return max(flatmax(i) for i in it)
    else:
        return it
```

Pensando en un caso más general, se puede hacer una versión funcional:

```
from functools import partial

def flat_functional(func, it):
    if hasattr(it, "__iter__"):
        return func(flat_functional(func, i) for i in it)
    else:
        return it

flatmax = partial(flat_functional, max)
flatmin = partial(flat_functional, min)
flatsum = partial(flat_functional, sum)
```

Yendo más allá, es posible hacer lo mismo, pero sin recursividad. Más compleja, pero tremendamente eficiente:

```
def flatten(it):
    for x in it:
        lst=[x]
        while lst:
            while hasattr(lst[0], "__iter__"):
                lst[0:1] = lst[0]
            yield lst.pop(0)


def flat_functional(func, it):
    return func(flatten(it))
```

NOTA: no funciona correctamente si algún elemento de la lista fuera una `string`.